# How can I process a push notification with NativeScript when the application is closed?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

The push notifications process works fine when the application is open, but when the application is closed it does process anything.

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I don't know the mechanism for sending push notifications. If your server sends them then it should work fine if the client is closed. If your client sends them then of course it can't send them if it is closed. If your client needs to send them when it reopens then your server needs to tell it the details of the push notifications it needs to send when it reopens.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Firebase, if you send a data message, then your callback function will be invoked as soon it hits the device but you will have to take care of displaying a notification on your own.